# Adaptive Card SDK is not getting properties color and weight

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm using Adaptive Cards SDK (`adaptativecards@2.11.1`) in my node application.
So I have this textBlock:

```
let card = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
card.version = new AdaptiveCards.Version(1, 0);

let textBlock = new AdaptiveCards.TextBlock();
textBlock.text = "Card Title";
textBlock.wrap = true;
textBlock.weight = "bolder";
textBlock.color = "good";
card.addItem(textBlock);
```

But when I console it

```
let json = card.toJSON();
console.log(json)
```

It's generating this json code:

```
 {
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  '$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
  version: '1.0',
  body: [ { type: 'TextBlock', 
            text: 'Card Title', 
            wrap: true 
       } ]
}
```

As you can see, the properties weight and color is not showing.

Does anyone know why its happening?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to build the card dynamically? Could you just create a JSON file containing your card and load it as needed? The Adaptive Cards library you're using is pretty old.

Comment: @AP01, I have dynamic data to send into card's content.. Are there other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The properties weight and color are not showing in the generated JSON because they are not part of the core Adaptive Cards schema.

The weight and color properties you are using are specific to the Microsoft Teams implementation of Adaptive Cards, which extends the core schema.

The weight and color properties are re specific to the Microsoft Teams implementation of Adaptive Cards
To include these Microsoft Teams-specific properties in your Adaptive Card, you need to add the "msteams" namespace to the card's code.

```
textBlock["msteams"] = {
  // Set the "weight" and "color" properties within the "msteams" namespace
  weight: "bolder",
  color: "good"
};
```

By adding the "msteams" namespace and setting the weight and color properties within that namespace, you can get the color and weight properties in your json.

Comment: thanks in advance for your answear, I added the excectly code that you told, but it still not working. There are anything to do? I didn´t understand what this "msteams" in textBlock means. Tku so much.